# mysql unique number generation

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I want to generate a unique random integer (from 10000 to 99999) identity just by clean mySQL; any ideas?

I don't want to generate this number in php by cycling (generate number -> check it in database) because I want to use some intelligent solution in a mySQL query.

Comment: unique to what, other entries in the table?

Comment: Checking for that will require a custom function, which over time, will get progressively slower as the pool of available numbers depletes.  ie: Generate random #, check table, exists? regenerate, check table, exists?...

Comment: If this is for the purposes of generating a unique ID for each row, please use an auto_increment field as per my answer - that's what they're for. :-)

Comment: @hippout meaning you want a number that is in the given range that is not in a table column? Do you want to track previous outputs as well, i.e. not allow the query to produce the same number later?

Comment: @middaparka yes auto_increment generates orders in a pre-defined order but the OP asked for a unique random integer. I also have had need for such a number and I used the create-check cycle - but I would prefer a better way.

Answer (score 21):

While it seems somewhat awkward, this is what can be done to achieve the goal:

```
SELECT FLOOR(10000 + RAND() * 89999) AS random_number
FROM table
WHERE random_number NOT IN (SELECT unique_id FROM table)
LIMIT 1
```

Simply put, it generates N random numbers, where N is the count of table rows, filters out those already present in the table, and limits the remaining set to one.

It could be somewhat slow on large tables. To speed things up, you could create a view from these unique ids, and use it instead of nested select statement.

EDIT: removed quotes

Comment: One thing to be aware of, which can cause issues, is that this requires that there is at least one record in `table`. Otherwise, no random number will be returned.

Comment: Don't use quotes!  It will be a string, which will be treated as the number `0`.

Comment: @unclenorton I keep getting `> 1054 - Unknown column 'random_number`' in 'where clause'.

Comment: how can you update the existing field with this query??

Answer (score 6):

Build a look-up table from sequential numbers to randomised id values in range 1 to 1M:

```
create table seed ( i int not null auto_increment primary key );
insert into seed values (NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),
                        (NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL);

insert into seed select NULL from seed s1, seed s2, seed s3, seed s4, seed s5, seed s6;
delete from seed where i < 100000;

create table idmap ( n int not null auto_increment primary key, id int not null );
insert into idmap select NULL, i from seed order by rand();

drop table seed;

select * from idmap limit 10;

+----+--------+
| n  | id     |
+----+--------+
|  1 | 678744 |
|  2 | 338234 |
|  3 | 469412 |
|  4 | 825481 |
|  5 | 769641 |
|  6 | 680909 |
|  7 | 470672 |
|  8 | 574313 |
|  9 | 483113 |
| 10 | 824655 |
+----+--------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

(This all takes about 30 seconds to run on my laptop.  You would only need to do this once for each sequence.)

Now you have the mapping, just keep track of how many have been used (a counter or auto_increment key field in another table).

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with the solution here for a while and then realised it fails if the column has NULL entries.  I reworked this with the following code;

```
SELECT FLOOR(10000 + RAND() * 89999) AS my_tracker FROM Table1 WHERE "tracker" NOT IN (SELECT tracker FROM Table1 WHERE tracker IS NOT NULL) LIMIT 1
```

Fiddle here;
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/620de1/1

Hope its helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

The only half-way reasonable idea I can come up with is to create a table with a finite pool of IDs and as they are used remove them from that table.  Those keys can be unique and a script could be created to generate that table.  Then you could pull one of those keys by generating a random select from the available keys.  I said 'half-way' reasonable and honestly that was being way to generous, but it beats randomly generating keys until you create a unique one I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, implemented in Cakephp 2.4.7, is to create a table with one auto_incremental type field

```
CREATE TABLE `unique_counters` (
  `counter` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`counter`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I then created a php function so that every time insert a new record, reads the generated id and delete it immediately.
Mysql keeps in its memory counter status. All the numbers generated are unique until you reset the mysql counter or you run a TRUNCATE TABLE operation

find below the Model created in Cakephp to implement all

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * UniqueCounter Model
 *
 */
class UniqueCounter extends AppModel {

/**
 * Primary key field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $primaryKey = 'counter';

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $validate = array(
        'counter' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
    );

    public function get_unique_counter(){
        $data=array();
        $data['UniqueCounter']['counter']=0;
        $data['UniqueCounter']['field']=1;

        if($this->save($data)){
            $new_id=$this->getLastInsertID();
            $this->delete($new_id);
            return($new_id);
        }
        return(-1);
    }
}
```

Any checks on the range of belonging of the result can be implemented in the same function,  by manipulating the result obtained

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique index on the field you want the unique random #

Then run

`Update IGNORE Table
Set RandomUniqueIntegerField=FLOOR(RAND() * 1000000);`

Answer (score -1):

The RAND() function will generate a random number, but will **not** guarantee uniqueness.  The proper way to handle unique identifiers in MySQL is to declare them using [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

For example, the id field in the following table will not need to be supplied on inserts, and it will always increment by 1:

```
CREATE TABLE animal (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: thanks, but i need RANDOM number (it's in my question), not autoincrement

Comment: Hmm, OK.  Without any more information, though, this just sounds like a Bad Idea.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4382586/662250), but it didn't work for me, so I had to change the original query a little.

```
SELECT FLOOR(1000 + RAND() * 89999) AS random_number
FROM Table
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE Table.ID=random_number) LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score -3):

I worry about *why* you want to do this, but you could simply use:

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 1000000);
```

See the full [MySQL RAND documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) for more information.

However, I hope you're not using this as a unique identifier (use an [auto_increment attribute](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) on a suitably large unsigned integer field if this is what you're after) and I have to wonder why you'd use MySQL for this and not a scripting language. What are you trying to achieve?