# Generate random unique code for each user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I would like to know how to generate in both PHP and SQL a unique random code for each user. This code will be used in the url of users' webpages.

For example, the website https://www.blablacar.fr/ uses the url https://www.blablacar.fr/user/show/random-unique-code-for-each-user
to access to the profile of that user.

I think I should use `uniqid` php function and store it in the database. But I don't know there is a better way to do so.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate unique random value for each user in laravel and add it to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524290/how-to-generate-unique-random-value-for-each-user-in-laravel-and-add-it-to-datab)

Comment: Maintain table with increment 0000001 and when creating get the last id add one (+1) and insert new value to above table and use that ID to create user. 100% Unique

Comment: Here is package you can solve problem without making another unique id 
https://github.com/vinkla/laravel-hashids

Answer (score 1):

You can use the current time to generate a unique string.

```
$unique = sha1(time);
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ramsey/uuid,

> ramsey/uuid is a PHP 5.4+ library for generating and working with RFC
>   4122 version 1, 3, 4, and 5 universally unique identifiers (UUID).

This package is used by dafult for generating uniqueids in laravel framework. if you are using laravel `uniqid()` function will give you the required unique id,

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). As mentioned by [@Shobi P P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2693543/shobi-p-p) Laravel uses the package [`ramsey/uuid`](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid)

> A PHP 5.4+ library for generating RFC 4122 version 1, 3, 4, and 5 universally unique identifiers (UUID).

So you could just import the package and use its function to generate an UUID

```
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Exception\UnsatisfiedDependencyException;

public function yourMethod()
{
    try {
        // Generate a version 1 (time-based) UUID object
        $uuid1 = Uuid::uuid1();
        echo $uuid1->toString() . "\n"; // i.e. e4eaaaf2-d142-11e1-b3e4-080027620cdd
    } catch (UnsatisfiedDependencyException $e) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
}
```

PS:

Taylor Otwell has posted an [poll](https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/953356466848698370) on whether to include the UUID function to the Str class.

Answer (score 0):

Random code can be generated by using `str_random(length)` function. You can generate a random code and attach the current time-stamp to that string. Which is unique I think.

Answer (score 0):

Custom:

```
  function generateRandomStr($length = 8) {
        $UpperStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        $LowerStr = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        $symbols = "0123456789";
        $characters = $symbols.$LowerStr.$UpperStrl;
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomStr = null;
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $randomStr .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        return $randomStr;
    }

    echo generateRandomStr(8).generateRandomStr(8);
```

or use http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use [base_convert()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) function to generate unique id

```
base_convert ( string $number , int $frombase , int $tobase )
```

See the example code here: https://txeditor.com/jh6o8d1ldsd