# In laravel how to create unique and random number

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to store unique and random student_registration_id number. If I create 5000 user registration that time also it should be unique and it should 10 digit and also I am storing student image below image storing unique id is perfect or not.

**Code**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

  $this->validate($request, [

      'student_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
      'student_father_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
      'student_mother_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
      'student_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',  

]);

    $input['student_photo'] = time().'.'.$request->student_photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $folder1 = public_path('STUDENT_DATA/STUDENT_PHOTO/');
    $path1 = $folder1 . $input['student_photo']; // path 1
    $request->student_photo->move($folder1, $input['student_photo']); // image saved in first folder
    $path2 = public_path('../../../abc.com/public/STUDENT_DATA/STUDENT_PHOTO/') . $input['student_photo']; // path 2
    \File::copy($path1, $path2);

       $input['student_name'] = strtoupper ($request['student_name']);
       $input['student_father_name'] = strtoupper ($request['student_father_name']);
       $input['student_mother_name'] = strtoupper ($request['student_mother_name']);

       $input['student_registration_id'] ="SIIT_".time();        
    Student::create($input);    
   return back()->with('success',' STUDENT REGISTERD SUCCESSFULLY .');
}
```

Comment: use time function with unique id & md5 function like this. `md5(uniqid().time())`

Comment: @Webbinion who to maintain 10 digit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate unique random value for each user in laravel and add it to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524290/how-to-generate-unique-random-value-for-each-user-in-laravel-and-add-it-to-datab)

Comment: Answer accepted in @pringi's link is a correct answer to your problem and to be absolutely certain to never have collision.

Comment: @cbaconnier how to implement pringi provided linked answer in my code i am confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per your request, here's how to implement the [suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28524418/8068675) with your code

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{

  $this->validate($request, [
      'student_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
      'student_father_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
      'student_mother_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
      'student_photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048',  
]);

    $input['student_photo'] = time().'.'.$request->student_photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $folder1 = public_path('STUDENT_DATA/STUDENT_PHOTO/');
    $path1 = $folder1 . $input['student_photo']; // path 1
    $request->student_photo->move($folder1, $input['student_photo']); // image saved in first folder
    $path2 = public_path('../../../abc.com/public/STUDENT_DATA/STUDENT_PHOTO/') . $input['student_photo']; // path 2
    \File::copy($path1, $path2);

    $input['student_name'] = strtoupper ($request['student_name']);
    $input['student_father_name'] = strtoupper ($request['student_father_name']);
    $input['student_mother_name'] = strtoupper ($request['student_mother_name']);

    $id = $this->generateRegistrationId();
    $input['student_registration_id'] = $id;
    DB::table('locations')->insert([['center_code' => $id]])

    Student::create($input); 

   return back()->with('success',' STUDENT REGISTERD SUCCESSFULLY .');
}

function generateRegistrationId() {
    $id = 'SIIT_' . mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999); // better than rand()

    // call the same function if the id exists already
    if ($this->registrationIdExists($id)) {
        return $this->generateRegistrationId();
    }

    // otherwise, it's valid and can be used
    return $id;
}

function registrationIdExists($id) {
    // query the database and return a boolean
    // for instance, it might look like this in Laravel
    return Student::where('student_registration_id', $id)->exists();
}
```

Comment: how to maintain digits length

Comment: What do you mean? `'SIIT_' . mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999);` will generate a number between `1000000000` to `9999999999` which will **always** be 10 digits as you desired. Example of id generated : `'SIIT_1234567890`

Comment: i what to save id value hear also but value are not same DB::table('locations')->insert([['center_code' => $this->generateRegistrationId()]]);

Answer (score 0):

You could use this: 
 `hexdec(uniqid());` 
`uniqid()` - returns unique numbers but in their hexadecimal representation and therefore you will have to use: 
`hexdec()` to convert it to their decimal representation.