# Insert a random int that does not exist in Dtabase not working?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

mt_rand() and random_int() both are generate only one numbe and insert it in database where the number is already exist. I want to clear that , I want to insert a random number that is not exist in database.

I took this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524290/how-to-generate-unique-random-value-for-each-user-in-laravel-and-add-it-to-datab)

In my case in laravel 8, the code looks like below

```
public function generateProductCode() {
    $number = mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999); 

    // call the same function if the barcode exists in Dtabase already
    if ($this->productCodeExists($number)) {
        return $this->generateProductCode();
    }

    // otherwise, it's valid and can be used
    return $number;
}

public function productCodeExists($number) {
    // query the database and return a boolean
    // for instance, it might look like this in Laravel
    return Product::where('product_code', $number)->exists();
}
```

The model name is Product and DB table name is products. 'product_code' is the column where I want to do this query.
In store function where I Call generateProductCode() function, it looks like below

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $product = new Product;
    //Generate a Product key
    $product->product_code = $this->generateProductCode();
    $product->save();
 }
```

It returns all time only one numbers that is ***2147483647*** .
[Photo is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1XBL.png)
What is the wrong? What is the perfect query to check exist so that it returns another that is not exist in the database.

Comment: use `random_int()` instead of `mt_rand()`, with same parameters

Comment: You could just use the [Uuid](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-str-uuid) helper that ships with Laravel.

Comment: make primary key in this model in uuid - and all other things will be automatic.

Comment: mt_rand() and random_int() both are generate only one number. and insert it database where the number is already exist. I want to clear that , I want to insert a random number that is not exist in database.

Comment: `2147483647` is the maximum signed integer you can have on a 32 bit system which seems like what you have. You should indeed use a UUID to generate unique identifiers and in that case you probably don't even need to check they are unique.

Comment: Make your field `product_code` - `BIGINT UNSIGNED`

Comment: Thanks @all you all are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a recursion function check if the number is already used or not.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $product = new Product;
    //Generate a Product key
    $product->product_code = $this->newRandomInt();
    $product->save();
 }

 private function newRandomInt()
    {
        $number = random_int(1000000000, 9999999999); 
        $isUsed =  Product::where('number', $number)->first();
        if ($isUsed) {
            return $this->newRandomInt();
        }
        return $number;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

according to [php doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php):

> mt_rand: This function does not generate cryptographically secure
> values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes

you can use [random_int](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php)

it Generates cryptographic random integers that are suitable for use where unbiased results are critical

```
 $number = random_int(1000000000, 9999999999);
```

Comment: mt_rand() and random_int() both are generate only one number. and insert it database where the number is already exist. I want to clear that , I want to insert a random number that is not exist in database.