# Mysql random unique number not working

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I'm trying to get a unique code number which doesn't exists in the "codes" table using a query I found in several other SO threads:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25435263/471573
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11680058/471573

I'm currently trying to use this code:

```
CREATE TABLE codes (
  code int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `codes` (`code`) VALUES 
(1),(2),(3),(4),(5); 

 SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 10) AS `rand_code` 
   FROM `codes` 
  WHERE "rand_code" NOT IN (SELECT `code` FROM `codes`) 
  LIMIT 1
```

sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e807/2

With lots of issues:

1. if no codes are in the table, I get no results at all.
2. if there ARE any codes, the results is not unique. I can get a result already in the table...

Any idea on how to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: One option, assuming you plan to do something like this in the real world, would be to use a UUID which is very unlikely to ever be generated again.  Then handle that unlikely edge case by just generating another UUID.  Make the UUID column in your database table unique.

Comment: Edit your question and put sample data and desired results in as text tables.

Comment: Perhaps you're approaching the problem from the wrong end.

Answer (score 0):

`rand()` is evaluated everywhere it appears in the query.  To do what you want, you can repeatedly run a query like this:

```
SELECT r.rand_code
FROM (SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * 10) as rand_code) r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM codes c WHERE c.code = r.rand_code);
```

This may not return a row.  Then you need to re-run it.

Or, because you have such a limited number of codes, use a derived table to generate all of them, then randomly choose among the ones that don't exist:

```
select r.rand_code
from (select 0 as rand_code union all select 1 . . .
      select 9
     ) r left join
     codes c
     on c.code = r.rand_ocde
where c.code is null
order by rand()
limit 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. However, I was hoping to avoid re-running queries, otherwise I'd just pick a random number in nodejs or php and test it against the DB, and re-run if it's already there etc...

Also, the codes are not limited.This was just a sample data. The real table could have lots and lots of codes (by the thousands), so that means the more codes it has, re-running the query will be much heavier on the server (running 10,20,100 queries etc...)